# добавление в список данных полученных при использовании класса Scanner

Tags: java

Я считываю сканером csv файл. и добавляю результат в список, но я получаю не то, что мне нужно. В списке получается всего один индекс(в котором массив данных). Мне потом надо преобразовать список в массив и перебрать его, но у этого списка всего один индекс, как добраться до массива внутри списка или сразу записать данные в список с пятью индексами?
вот фрагмент кода:

```
public class ReaderClass {
private void printFileContent(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
        List<City> cityList;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] splitLine = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
            cityList = Arrays.asList(new City(splitLine[1], splitLine[2], splitLine[3], splitLine[4], splitLine[5]));
            System.out.println(cityList[1]); // будет ошибка problems with the filejava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
                                                                                  Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

```
public class ReaderClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<City> cities = printFileContent(new FileInputStream("filename.csv"));
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i+=1) {//здесь меняете шаг, например, i+=4
            System.out.println(cities.get(i)); // здесь в консоль выводятся объекты, тут же в цикле можно искать максимальное число
        }
        
    }

    private static List<City> printFileContent(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
            List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] splitLine = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
                City city = new City(splitLine);
                cities.add(city);
            }
            return cities;
        }
    }
    
}

class City {
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final String republic;
    private final String region;
    private final Long population;
    private final Integer year;

    public City(String [] args) {
        this.id = Long.valueOf(args[0]);
        this.name = args[1];
        this.republic = args[2];
        this.region = args[3];
        this.population = Long.valueOf(args[4]);
        this.year = Integer.valueOf(args[5]);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRepublic() {
        return republic;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public Long getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City{" + "name=" + name + ", republic=" + republic + ", region=" + region + ", population=" + population + ", year=" + year + '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: не за что, пользуйтесь)

Comment: Все равно при вызове System.out.println(cities.get(4)); говорит, что Index 4 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: @Алексей System.out.println(cities.get(4));  - здесь вы пытаетесь дернуть запись с индексом 4 из коллекции, т.е. там должно быть минимум 5 записей. по представленным вами данным, я не могу гарантировать, что там столько есть. судя по ошибке, столько просто нет. посему для начала выведете в косноль всю коллекцию System.out.println(cities); , посмотрите сколько там записей. и вообще дергать что-то по индексу - странный ход...

Comment: Я поэтому и написал сюда, потому-что не понимаю как сделать, чтобы было 5 записей в списке, чтобы потом это преобразовать в массив и перебрать его

Comment: @Алексей тогда добавляйте сюда свой csv

Comment: В смысле, сюда файл кинуть? как

Comment: @Алексей сюда только текстом добавить к вопросу(если, конечно, их не 1000), который можно редактировать . но в целом проблема в том, что я не понимаю, что вы делаете. например, куда вы дописываете этот вывод в консоль? если так, как в вопросе, то это вообще всегда ошибка, без вариантов. вы не должны вносить изменения в мой метод. вы должны его вызвать, получить список вычитаных из файла данных и вывести его в консоль

Comment: Вот в таком формате текс в cvs:

Comment: Задача заключается в том, чтобы с помощью метода сканнер извлечь данные из csv файла и поместить  их  в список. Строчки в  csv файле выглядят так : 1;Адыгейск;Адыгея;Южный;12248;1973     и их действительно 1000, чуть больше. а после нужно полученный список преобразовать в массив и найти наибольшее число которое    находится на 4м индексе в каждой строчке(здесь это число например 12248) и вывести его. но у меня не получается это сделать. Для меня проблема в том, что список состоит из объектов, а каждый объект это массив из 5 элементов

Comment: @Алексей этот код не возвращает никакого массива объектов, этот код возвращает коллекцию объектов City. Я не знаю, как выглядит данный класс, поэтому написал его, исходя из строчки csv. Также сделал метод мейн, в котором прописал, как вызывать метод, плюс цикл для итераций по результату. Смотрите исправленный ответ, подставляйте имя вашего файла

Comment: Здорово!  спасибо, что уделили столько времени моему вопросу. Но не могли бы вы пояснить, что из себя представляет этот конструктор  public City(String [] args) {..

Comment: @Алексей у вас есть csv, вы читаете его построчно. разделителем там служит точка с запятой. для каждой строки вызывается split, который разбивает строку на части по указанному разделителю и в результате мы получаем массив строк. задача - преобразовать массив строк в объект city, учитывая то, что некоторые элементы массива нужно преобразовать в другой тип данных, например Long, Integer. Именно этот массив мы бросаем в конструктор, который и собирает из этого массива объект city , одновременно преобразовая типы.

Comment: @Алексей первая версия кода тоже будет работать. проблема именно в преобразовании данных, а оно вам надо, потому что вы хотите искать максимальное число, а для переменной типа стринг это невозможно. при таких исходных данных логичнее бросать массив в конструктор, чем пытаться сделать такие преобразования из цикла, который использует сканер. просто потому что все таки это поля объекта, пусть он с ними и разбирается, а сканер пусть читает. каждый выполняет свою роль.

Comment: теперь все понятно,  спасибо огромное!